# Tool for writing progress logs/documentation?

Tags: documentation, tracking, knowledge-management, backlog

I'm looking for tool (web application/service) that would allow me to write progress logs. I like to document what i'm doing over time, so i can look back what i was doing, what am i doing wrong, and so on. I know how to manage code projects using git, redmine, trac and so, but i am looking for something different.

I want to make daily logs of what i was doing. Currently i'm just writing wordpress posts and edit them daily, but that is not sufficient, because i want to group by days, projects and tasks and enable everything to be structured. I know i can put posts in categories using wordpress, but this way i have to make a new post for every day and i cannot simply refer to previous day, and tasks that were previous day unfinished. So basically i'm looking for some advanced diary tool.

Do you know any web app/service that would help me doing that, or do you prefer some other totally different approach. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please look through the [tag:pm-software] tagged questions and the [tag:tools] questions. Recommendation (and shopping questions) are off-topic and not a good fit for our site, but we have plenty of these types of questions still hanging around in those tags, which you may find helpful. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) and simply create an issue type called 'daily log' or log each activity separately within a 'logs' project so that you can mark them as completed or not. If you use JIRA for your bug tracking anyway then it would offer a quick way to get started on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [ohlife.com](http://ohlife.com/) which may be the one you are looking for. I've never tried it.